# When refilling toner, why only to half capacity?

Tags: laser-printer, toner

I am refilling my laser printer Samsung CLP 365. Toner supplier attached some not very impressive instructions paper that looks like just copied off google frankly. (Not in english)

It says toner cartridge should be refilled with a pre-measured amount to only half the cartridge capacity. Is this really necessary? I cannot find any instructions on the internet that also say that. There are many videos on YouTube showing how refilling is done, neither mentions it.

The instructions:
[image]

Comment: "Half" might be a good descriptive way of saying don't overfill which is very easy to do.  Toner is constantly turned over and "tilled"... It must be "loose"'fill it can't be "packed" tight when the chamber is closed.

Comment: Mind supplying as the translated instructions?

Comment: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?  "translated" was a key word in Ramhound's comment.  :-)